# QTableView, how to change dragging multiple items display

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtableview

I have a QTableView with my own implemented QAbstractItemModel, in which I can drag and drop multiple items inside. My problem is that when dragging the items and while trying to drop them in a destination cell, it is not so obvious for the user what the result is going to be. For example, I have the following,but I would prefer sth like the default widows displaying, which makes all 3 items like one item:

my QT Table

[image]

vs

windows dragging n dropping folders

[image]

Comment: So you want the image to change to a generic like windows?

Comment: QTableView or QTableWidget?

Comment: In my small example I use QTableWidget, but I think it is the same with QTableView. I would like to change the "drop" preview to sth more understandable, like for example instead of displaying three floating item, to display one icon (indicating 3) like in windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking this [tutorial](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html) as a reference, the mousePressEvent method is overwritten, and a new QPixmap is placed in QDrag:

```
void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton){

        QDrag *drag = new QDrag(this);
        drag->setMimeData(new QMimeData());
        drag->setPixmap(QPixmap("image.png"));

        drag->exec();
    }
    QTableView::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for information. You gave me the input for Qpixmap, but the solution didn't worked, because I also had a model implementation and mime data were ruined with mousePressEvent. I will post my final solution in case someone needs this

Answer (score 2):

After eyllanesc's suggestion for QPixmap, I found the correct solution to my problem, so that I can keep the mime data coming from my model. I have re-implemented startDrag(Qt::DropActions supportedActions) in my QTreeView class, so that when multiple objects are moved, one icon will be displayed along with the number of items moved. Now looks like this:

```
void MyTreeView::startDrag(Qt::DropActions supportedActions)
{
    QModelIndexList indexes = selectedIndexes();
    if (indexes.size() == 1)
        return QAbstractItemView::startDrag(supportedActions);
    if (indexes.count() > 0) 
    {
        QMimeData *data = model()->mimeData(indexes);
        if (!data)
           return;
        QRect rect; 
        rect.adjust(horizontalOffset(), verticalOffset(), 0, 0);
        QDrag *drag = new QDrag(this);

        ActionTreeItem* pItem = static_cast<ActionTreeItem*>(indexes[0].internalPointer());
        if (pItem != NULL)
        {
            QPixmap pixmap = myIcon.pixmap(myIcon.actualSize(QSize(32, 32)));
            QPainter *paint = new QPainter(&pixmap);
            paint->setPen(Qt::black);
            paint->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::white));
            QRect numberRect(18, 18, 13, 13);
            paint->drawRect(numberRect);
            paint->drawText(numberRect, Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter, QString("%1").arg(indexes.count()));
           drag->setPixmap(pixmap);
        }       
       drag->setMimeData(data);
       Qt::DropAction defaultDropAction = Qt::MoveAction;
       drag->exec(supportedActions, defaultDropAction);
    }
  }
```